# Electron postInst taking much time

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I am running node 5.0 on mac OS(Sierra), and trying to load node module of 'electron' using this command:

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

But the installation is stuck at `'node install.js'`, since 30 mins. There are no errors or any other log on screen.

Can someone please point me out in right direction.

Comment: Does this still happen if you kill the install process (press Ctrl+C), run `npm cache clean`, `rm -r ./node_modules` then `npm install` it all again?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yes, its still the same, I observed that it downloads a file, I mean increase network utility of 13.5 MB (approx) and then doing some processing(system calls and memory is varying). But still not sure, should it take this much time.